# Using Cjax to POST data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to POST some data using Cjax in CodeIgniter.

My view is:

```
<?php
  require_once(FCPATH . 'ajaxfw.php');
  $ajax->click('#subscribesubmit' , $ajax->form('ajax.php?subscriber/add/'));
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form class="form-inline subscribe-box" role="form" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="subscribemail">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribemail" name="subscribemail" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="subscribesubmit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This view is loaded in controller index().

My `subscriber` controller:

```
class Subscriber extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('subscriber_model');
        require_once(FCPATH.'ajaxfw.php');

    }

    public function add($subscribemail) {
        $ajax = ajax();
        //$email = $this->input->post('subscribemail');
        echo $subscribemail;
        $data['status'] = $this->subscriber_model->new_subscriber($subscribemail);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's in the **ajaxfw.php** file and what's the behaviour you're expecting but not getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in your code block  replace to:

```
require_once(FCPATH . 'ajax.php');
```

instead of:

```
require_once(FCPATH . 'ajaxfw.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include ajax.php instead of ajaxfw.php  (ajax.php would include itself ajaxfw.php if it needs to)